# How can I make my Ruby script (not Rails) run anywhere?

Tags: ruby, compilation

I'm very new to Ruby. I've recently finished writing a simple script, which uses a bunch of gems. It works well on my own workstation.

When I copied the script over to my laptop, it stopped working, even though I manually installed all the gems. I think it may be due to version differences in the gems installed, but I wanted to know if there might be any other reason. So:

1) Is there a way to have Ruby automatically install all of the required gems for a script, in their correct versions?

2) Could there be any other reason for the script running on one machine, yet failing on another?

Thank you in advance,
Mr. Rabid Cow.

Comment: You are missing a lot of necessary information in your question, such as errors displayed, versions of the Ruby interpreters on both machines, the paths for the accounts, etc.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "you manually installed all the gems"?

Comment: My knowledge is a little too vague to give a definitive answer, but have a read here and see if it helps: http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the program to work on any Windows system, i.e. even systems that don't have Ruby installed you should look at [OCRA](http://github.com/larsch/ocra).  This app creates a stand alone executable that contains your script, all the Ruby libs it needs, and the Ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

the first you should do is to read how to create a gem. In your own gem you can include information about which additional gems are required (also the specific version).

Take a look into http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/5

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea too.